# How do you allow existing users to join teams in Laravel Spark?

Tags: laravel-spark

It seems that spark only allows you to invite new users to join teams, how would existing users join a team?

Comment: I'll delete this once the bounty ends. Turns out it's really obvious, just not documented (like much of Spark's features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the existing user does get a notification, allowing them to join.
If no notification is received, then there is an issue here with the user or mail address.